# "frontend_input" is null against attribute I have loaded

Tags: attributes, collection, collection-filtering

I assume I am doing something wrong when loading this attribute but when I do: `$attribute->getFrontendInput()` it's null. I have also tried: `$attribute->getData("frontend_input")` to no avail.

When debugging I can also see the value is null.

I am loading the attribute like:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->setCodeFilter($code)
        ->load()
        ->getFirstItem();
```

**Edit**

Interestingly, I have dug into the `loadByCode` method and the SQL it runs: `SELECT`eav_attribute`.* FROM`eav_attribute`WHERE (`eav_attribute`.`attribute_code`='udaattr_choice') AND (entity_type_id = 4)` returns `frontend_input` as null as well.

I will have to check my code that creates the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get your attribute like this:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $code);
```

Then look in the `$attribute->getData()` to see what you can get from there.
**[EDIT]**
If you still get `null` as a result then the value is null in the db.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. I now have 36 values against `$attribute` but `frontend_input` is still null.

Comment: Then maybe `frontend_input` is really `null`. Check the `eav_attribute` table and see the value in there.

Comment: See my edit. I did that and it actually is null. I should trust my code more ^^ Thanks for your time.

Comment: :). I still say you should use the code I provided to get your attribute. In theory you can have 2 attributes with the same code for 2 different entities. Retrieving it like you do, there is a chance you get the wrong attribute (for the second entity). The best example is `url_key`. There is one for categories and one for products.

Comment: Ah right, Ok. Thanks very much. Could you add something to your answer stating that the value is null in the DB if the above doesn't work. Will mark as answer then. Seems deserved even though I found the same results.

Comment: @webnoob. I added a few words.